# How to Check RTMP Live stream is on or off

Tags: php, ffmpeg, rtmp

I want to check RTMP live stream  is on or off for mic.

I have used RTMP DUMP

```
exec("/usr/bin/rtmpdump -V -v -r rtmp://www.exapmle.com/etc./13/mic1 -o /tmp/rtmp-checker.log 2>&1", $pp);
```

I have found this trick from
http://blog.svnlabs.com/how-to-check-rtmp-source-stream-is-live-or-not/

But I am not satisfied with the result because it doesn't always work, and generates a random string as a result.

![So some time i am facing this type of error. any perfect solution for this.?][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrTco.png

I'm looking for solutions with ffmpeg, or something else.

Comment: Thank you, just what i needed. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams rtmp://example.com/stream
```

You'll get a return code `1` if the command failed or `0` and a JSON string containing the detected streams on success:

```
{
    "index": 1,
    "codec_name": "aac",
    "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
    "profile": "LC",
    "codec_type": "audio",
    ...
}
```

This is a basic test, if you want to go further than that you could download a few seconds of the stream, validate it with `ffprobe`, run `silencedetect` on it etc.

Comment: I get the Response as you have mention for the rtmp in which music is on but it continuously processing and not get any response for the rtmp When  my mic is off. 

if I on the mic than I get the response like yours. can you please explain reason and solution?.. 

Thanks

Comment: You can try lowering `-probesize` (in bytes, default 5 mb). If it still gets stuck forever then the alternative is to use the linux `timeout` command: `timeout 10s ffprobe ...`. It will return `124` if the command timeouts, in which case you raise an alert and check the stream.

Comment: Is it nessesary to include the `-print_format json` and the `-show_streams` options?
After a some tests it looks like to me that the method works even if you rely on the exitcode exclusively, while omitting both options.

Comment: @GergelyLukacsy It's not necessary if you don't need stream information. The question was about a microphone stream thus the check for an audio stream.

Comment: @aergistal Thanks for clarifying.
Yeah, I was aware of the OP's exact problem.